# Make absolute div height 100% even when scrollbar is visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div class="modalPage"style="display:none;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.modalPage{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:0.6;
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    z-index:100;
    top:0px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".modalPage").toggle();
```

Effect:

[image]

Now there is a layer above everything. So the user cannot interact with the website anymore.

Problem:

[image]

When scrollbar appears because of much content, the layer actually does not stretch in height like you see in the image.

How can I make the absolute div stretch automatically?

Comment: used to fixed position and left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0; ...........don't used with or height.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.................................

hi now **don't** used `width` or `height` and now used to position `fixed`

as like this

```
.modalPage{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#000000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:0.6;
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.modalPage{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:0.6;
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```